# A homomorphism $\phi_X: \mathbb{R} \to G$ is uniquely determined by the tangent vector $\phi_X'(0) = X$.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

This is the first part of Exercise 8.31 of Fulton and Harris: (paraphrased)

> Show that $\phi_X:\mathbb{R} \to G$ is uniquely determined by the fact that 1. it is a homomorphism and 2. $\phi_X'(0) = X$.

$G$ is a Lie group, and I believe I am also to assume $\phi_X$ is additionally smooth (or perhaps this follows?).

I have proven that the vector field on $\text{Im}(\phi_X)$ given by $\phi_X'(t)$ is left-invariant: Because $\phi_X$ is a homomorphism, we have $$\phi_X = m_{(\phi_X(t))^{-1}} \circ \phi_X \circ A_t$$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ where $m_{\phi_X(t)}$ is  left multiplication by $\phi_X(t)$ and $A_t$ is translation by $t$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Differentiating,

$$X = \phi_X'(0) = d(m_{(\phi_X(t))^{-1}})_{\phi_X(t)}\circ \phi_X'(t)$$

and re-arranging,

$$\phi_X'(t) = d(m_{\phi_X(t)})_e(X).$$

So the vector field on $\text{Im}(\phi_X)$ given by $\phi_X'$ can be computed from just $\phi_X'(0) = X$. What I want to do at this stage is invoke uniqueness of flow lines, and argue that the flow line through $e$ is exactly $\phi_X$ (vaguely inspired by the definition of one-parameter subgroups). I have two issues here: 1. It would seem that I need to extend the vector field on $\text{Im}(\phi_X)$ to all of $G$, and this extension needn't be unique. 2. How would I then claim that the flow line through the origin is $\phi_X$? Is this strategy even correct?

Any help would be appreciated. This seems like a very fundamental idea/argument in Lie groups, so I want to really understand it.

Comment: In this case Fulton is talking about Lie group homomorphism, otherwise condition 2 wouldn't make sense. As for questions 1 and 2, you can define X in all of G by just declaring it to be left-invariant and specifying its value at e. Then use the uniqueness of integral curves. You will end up learning that the one-parameter subgroups are in bijection with the Lie algebra of G. I recommend you Broker and tom Dieck's book, you'll get a good feeling of the foundations on Lie theory.

Comment: I understand that I can can define $X$ on all of $G$ by declaring it to be left-invariant. I don't see how this helps here, since this extension isn't unique (and a priori, neither are the resulting integral curves)---I'm trying to prove $\phi_X$ is uniquely determined! Perhaps I'm missing something...

Comment: A vector field is left-invariant iff for all $g\in G$, we have $X_g = d(L_g)_e (X_e)$. So, a left-invariant vector field is $\underline{uniquely}$ determined by its value at $e\in G$. So, you just have to prove that $\phi_X$ is the integral curve of the left-invariant vector field whose initial condition at $e$ is $X$.

Comment: I'm well aware that left invariant vector fields are determined by the value at $e$, as I am aware that I need to prove $\phi_X$ is the integral curve of the vector field corresponding to $X$---this is exactly the content of my question: how do I do that? I have proven that for every point $g$ in the image of $\phi_X$, the vector field at that point is $d(L_g)_e(X)$, and I am asking how I can use this fact to finish the exercise.

Comment: Let us abuse the notation and define $X$ to be the unique left-invariant vector field on $G$ with initial condition $X$ at $e$. Then for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $X_{\phi_X(t)} = d(L_{\phi_X(t)})_e (X) = d(L_{\phi_X(t)})_e (\phi_X '(0)) = \frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0} \phi_X(t) \phi_X (s) = \frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0} \phi_X (t+s) = \phi_X '(t)$.

Comment: What you have just proven is exactly what I have proven in the body of my post: that $\phi_X'(t) = X_{\phi_X(t)}$. By itself, this is not sufficient to show $\phi_X$. My question is essentially asking how to proceeded from here.

Comment: What you proved is not even remotely close to what I did. For starters, you proved that $\phi_X '$ (which is not a vector field, but merely a vector field along $\phi$) is left-invariant only by the left translations given by the image of the subgroup. This if of course not enough to guarantee uniqueness. But then I tell you how to extend it to a left-invariant vector field on all of $G$ by just using its initial condition, and you say the extension may not be unique, which is of course false.

Comment: Then I prove that $\phi_X$ is the integral curve of the unique (smoothness is left to you) left-invariant vector field with initial condition $X$ at $e$, you still don't get the uniqueness. Summing-up, 1) left-invariant vector fields are smooth and uniquely determined by their value at $e$, 2) integral curves of a smooth vector field are uniquely determined by their initial condition. I think you still lack a basic background on Analysis on Manifolds and Lie groups, which is why I advised you to strengthen it first.